Disable ICMPv6, IGMPv2 and other network protocols
I'm the IT guy for a small office that started to get not so small anymore, so we got a switch and a windows server active directory. Then some security concerns started to appear, so i searched the web watched some videos and learned that LLMNR and NetBIOS are bad so i disabled them, but when i run wireshark there are still a lot of stuff happening that i don't think i need and may or may not be vulnerabilities like:

ICMPv6 - This one is used for host discovery, computers only need to communicate with the server not with each other

IGMPv2 - This one is used for multicast, i'm thinking about making
all switch ports (except the server and the router ones) protected because computers only need to communicate with the server not with each other, so multicast in general sounds unnecessary

ARP - This one is just straight up meant for hackers to man in the middle attack some stuff

SSDP - This one is used for advertisement and discovery of network services, which i don't think i need

MDNS - I already have a DNS with windows server


I'm new to this sysadmin thing and would like to know if i'm terribly wrong about something, my only goal is to make the company information secure.

I'll just quickly note that generally ARP doesn't traverse a router at the edge of the public Internet, because what's on the private side of the router is not addresses that are visible to the Internet at large. That said, on each side of the router it remains critical to keep that going, as there is no other way for a router to know where it should be sending information.

You are terribly wrong to the level that I'm contemplating if you're serious or trolling.

Sorry to be blunt, but you don't really seem to know what you are talking about.
ARP deserves a special mention, because it's vital to map IP addresses to MAC addresses, i.e. to identify which physical network interface connected to a switch has a certain IP address.
Without ARP, Ethernet networks just couldn't possibly work.

Same can be said for ICMPv6 - without it, IPv6 won't work.
